# Representing any square matrix by the product of invertible and idempotent

Tags: linear-algebra

> For any square matrix $A$, we can find an invertible matrix $B$ and an idempotent matrix $P$, such that $$A=BP$$

My thought:

Since we can do column and row operation on $A$ and get:

$$ UAV=
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
I & O \\
O & O
\end{array}\right)
$$
In which $U$ and $V$ are invertible matrics, and RHS is an idempotent.

So I can now represent $A$ by:
$$ A=U^{-1}
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
I & O \\
O & O
\end{array}\right)V^{-1}
$$

But still not the representing we want.

May I get some hint? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: from where you left off,

$A=U^{-1}V^{-1}\left(V\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}V^{-1}\right)$